# JSON XML conversion issue-whitespace

Tags: java, xml, json

I am trying to convert a json string  to xml using json lib-2.4.jar and  I am getting the following exception.

Exception in thread "main" nu.xom.IllegalNameException: 0x20 is not a legal NCName character
        at nu.xom.Verifier.throwIllegalNameException(Unknown Source)

I have identified the issue as there is a whitespace character(0x20) in the 'location' tag of json string and it’s not getting parsed properly. I have removed the space and tested once then it works as expected. I have also tried different ways to remove white space characters by using StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml and some custom methods like below

```
StringBuffer s1 = new StringBuffer();
  for (char c : value.toCharArray()) {// value is the json string
    // System.out.println(c);
       s1.append(c);
       if (c == 0x20) {
       s1.append(" ");
        }
       }
```

but none of these approaches are giving expected result.

I am also attaching the Json string below.

```
{
"ArticleList": [
{
"hash": "4b8e81ec1197aa071eb62238465e4cf4",
"data":{"twitter":{"id":"276992360028712960","text":"{James 2:13} Mercy triumphs over judgment.","source":"<a href=\"http://www.abcd.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">TweetCaster<\/a>","created_at":"Fri, 07 Dec 2012 10:11:39 +0000","user":{"id":12121,"location":"{GALATIANS 2:20}","friends_count":153,"description":"Drafter#Photographer","name":"Ervin","created_at":"Sat, 28 Jan 2012 00:26:08 +0000","screen_name":"E_doubleU","id_str":"476305028","statuses_count":1212,"lang":"en","followers_count":114}},"salience":{"content":{"sentiment":0}},"klout":{"score":31},"interaction":{"id":"1e240567d69faf80e","content":"{James 2:13} because Mercy triumphs over judgment.","schema":{"version":3},"author":{"id":4763,"username":"E_doubleU","link":"http://twitter.com/","name":"Ervin wooddruff","avatar":"http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2921703982/13ff21c643da6b748f279baee376f58c_normal.jpeg"},"source":"TweetCaster  Android","link":"http://twitter.com/","created_at":"Fri, 07 Dec 2012 10:11:39 +0000","type":"twitter"},"language":{"tag":"en","confidence":90},"demographic":{"gender":"male"}}}
]
}
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciable

Comment: Seems like a bug in the library. The value of the `location` property is a string, so there's no reason why a space should be a problem. It seems like it's getting confused because the string begins with `{`, so it thinks it's an object. But since it's in quotes, the braces don't have any special meaning.

Comment: See some workaround via links [json-lib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641966/remove-white-space-from-xml-element-using-java/30665244#30665244), [gson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228343/replace-whitespace-in-json-keys) for different json libraries

Answer (score 0):

There is some mismatch of which characters are allowed in a JSON tag and in an XML tag. Fore example, a blank is valid in a JSON tag but not in an XML tag. So if you need to come up with a general solution, you will have to invent some way to represent the not allowed characters in your xml tags by escape sequences.

Its not completely clear from your question, but I suppose the problem is that you actually get something like `..., " location":"{GALATIANS..."` as your JSON string and that this is a problem in the sender and the tag should actually just be "location". If this is the case you could use the `java.lang.String.trim` method to get rid of the leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Hi Henry, Thanks for your response.

The issue is same as you mentioned.

If I add  a space (" ")  at the end of the location tag before it closes with double quotes("). Then it works properly.

"location":"{GALATIANS 2:20}",  // this is throwing an exception.
"location":"{GALATIANS 2:20} ",  // this is working as expected.

I think it's a problem with library.