# Replace whitespace in JSON keys

Tags: java, json, parsing

I am thinking of a best solution to replace all the whitespaces in JSON keys with underscore.

```
{ 
  "Format": "JSON", 
  "TestData": { 
    "Key with Spaces in it": { 
      "And Again": { 
        "Child_Key1": "Financial", 
        "Child_Key2": null 
      }, 
......... 
.....
```

I want the above to be converted as shown below:

```
{ 
  "Format": "JSON", 
  "TestData": { 
    "Key_with_Spaces_in_it": { 
      "And_Again": { 
        "Child_Key1": "Financial", 
        "Child_Key2": null 
      }, 
......... 
.....
```

Any suggestions ?

Does any Java library have any predefined function to do this ?

Comment: If it is about parsing the JSON into an Object, the best way is to use `@JsonProperty("Key with Spaces in it")`. See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations for more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Replacing Keys**

The following code uses Google's JSON parser to extract keys, reformat them, and then create a new JSON object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String testJSON = "{\"TestKey\": \"TEST\", \"Test spaces\": { \"child spaces 1\": \"child value 1\", \"child spaces 2\": \"child value 2\" } }";
    Map oldJSONObject = new Gson().fromJson(testJSON, Map.class);
    JsonObject newJSONObject = iterateJSON(oldJSONObject);

    Gson someGson = new Gson();
    String outputJson = someGson.toJson(newJSONObject);
    System.out.println(outputJson);
}

private static JsonObject iterateJSON(Map JSONData) {
    JsonObject newJSONObject = new JsonObject();
    Set jsonKeys = JSONData.keySet();
    Iterator<?> keys = jsonKeys.iterator();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String currentKey = (String) keys.next();
        String newKey = currentKey.replaceAll(" ", "_");
        if (JSONData.get(currentKey) instanceof Map) {
            JsonObject currentValue = iterateJSON((Map) JSONData.get(currentKey));
            newJSONObject.add(currentKey, currentValue);
        } else {
            String currentValue = (String) JSONData.get(currentKey);
            newJSONObject.addProperty(newKey, currentValue);
        }
    }
    return newJSONObject;
}
```

You can read more about GSON [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

**Replacing Values**

Depending on how your JSON data is set up, you might need to switch JSONArray with JSONObject.

JSONArrays begin and end with `[]`, while JSONObjects begin and end with `{}`

In short, these methods will travel over an entire array/object and replace any spaces with underscores. They're recursive, so they will dive into child JSONArrays/JSONObjects.

If the JSON data is encoded as a Java JSONArray, you can do the following:

```
public static void removeJSONSpaces(JSONArray theJSON) {
    for (int i = 0; while i < theJSON.length(); i++) {
        if (theJSON.get(i) instanceof JSONArray) {
            currentJSONArray = theJSON.getJSONArray(i);
            removeJSONSpaces(currentJSONArray);
        } else {
            currentEntry = theJSON.getString(i);
            fixedEntry = currentEntry.replace(" ", "_");
            currentJSONArray.put(i, fixedEntry);
        }
    }
}
```

In short, this method will travel over an entire array and replace any spaces with underscores. It's recursive, so it will dive into child JSONArrays.

You can read more about JSONArrays [here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html)

If the data is encoded as a JSONObject, you'd want to do something like:

```
public static void removeJSONSpaces(JSONObject theJSON) {

    jObject = new JSONObject(theJSON.trim());
    Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        if (jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
            removeJSONSpaces(jObject.get(key))
        } else {
            currentEntry = theJSON.getString(i);
            fixedEntry = currentEntry.replace(" ", "_");
            currentJSONArray.put(i, fixedEntry);
        }
    }

}
```

You can read more about JSONObjects [here](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: I really appreciate your response, Your idea looks good. But I want to rename the name of the key itself, how a put() will rename the key ? Wont it become a value ? I am bit confused here.

Comment: Also this will only replace the extreme child keys, not all the keys :(

Comment: Man, Any more comments on this ? Your thoughts could trigger a better solution here :)

Comment: Howdy, as I mentioned put is not the exact solution. But I had tweaked your solution a but. In both key and value, I am replacing space with _SP_, symbols with _SYMBOL_KEYWORD_ . Then that resolves my problem. As I have a external response mapping to do, I am using xslt to replace this with actual value, for example _SP_ with ' '

Comment: the type names have changed slightly in `gson 2.8.2` -  `JSONArray` is now `JsonArray` & `JSONObject` is now `JsonObject`

Answer (score 1):

You can just read in each of the keys/values then use the `String replace(String oldString, String newString)` method.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
      String testJSON = "{\"menu\": {\n" +
        "  \"id no\": \"file\",\n" +
        "  \"value type\": \"File\",\n" +
        "  \"popup value\": {\n" +
        "    \"menu item\": [\n" +
        "      {\"value\": \"New\", \"onclick\": \"CreateNewDoc()\"},\n" +
        "      {\"value\": \"Open\", \"onclick\": \"OpenDoc()\"},\n" +
        "      {\"value\": \"Close\", \"onclick\": \"CloseDoc()\"}\n" +
        "    ]\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}}";
             JSONObject json = new JSONObject(testJSON);
             System.out.println("Final output: "+replaceKeyWhiteSpace(json));
```

replace the WhiteSpace with "_"

```
private static JSONObject replaceKeyWhiteSpace(Object json) {
JSONObject jsonObject = null;
if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
    jsonObject = (JSONObject) json;
    List<String> keyList = new LinkedList<String>(jsonObject.keySet());
    for (String key : keyList) {
        if (!key.matches(".*[\\s\t\n]+.*")) {
            Object value = jsonObject.get(key);
            replaceKeyWhiteSpace(value);
            continue;
        }

        Object value = jsonObject.remove(key);
        String newKey = key.replaceAll("[\\s\t\n]", "_");

        replaceKeyWhiteSpace(value);

        jsonObject.accumulate(newKey, value);

    }
} else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
    for (Object aJsonArray : (JSONArray) json) {
        replaceKeyWhiteSpace(aJsonArray);
    }
}
return jsonObject;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am using gson library in order to remove bad keys from json string because I want to create the AVRO file of the json.
Keys with spaces or non Alphanumeric are not acceptable from Avro so I have to sanitize input first.

The above snippet removes whitespaces and character $ from all keys (iterative). I assume my json string is JsonObject.

Check out a small sample code that I have used.

```
for (String json: allJsons){
        JsonObject schema = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject cleanSchema = new JsonObject();
        Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = schema.entrySet();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry: entries) {
            String key = entry.getKey().replace("$","").replace(" ","");
            JsonElement value = entry.getValue();
            if (value.isJsonObject()){
                JsonObject subValue = new JsonObject();
                Set <Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> subEntries = ((JsonObject) value).entrySet();
                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> subEntry: subEntries) {
                    String subKey = subEntry.getKey().replace("$","").replace(" ","");
                    subValue.add(subKey, subEntry.getValue());
                }
                value = subValue;
            }
            cleanSchema.add(key, value);
        }

        System.out.println("Clean schema "+cleanSchema.toString());
        byte[] bytes = converter.convertToAvro(cleanSchema.toString().getBytes(), avroSchema);
        String avroFile = outputFileName+"_"+counter+".avsc";
        Files.write(Paths.get(avroFile), bytes);
        counter++;
        System.out.println("Avro File Created "+avroFile);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to remove white space from Json Keys. Solution will work for JsonArray and JsonObject, just printing matching regex keys with white space and replace those keys.
Live Demo : [online Java compiler](http://tpcg.io/lV1R3LGc)

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class MatcherGroupExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text   = "{\"co nf ig\": {\"oauthSecret\": [{\"i d\": 45,\"config123\": {\"oauthSecret\": \"P8n2x5Ht0nFRRB0A\",\"status\": \"CREATED\"},\"SERVER132\": \"1000\"},{\"id\": 46,\"config123\": {\"oauthSecret\": \"wP8n2x5Ht0nFRRB0A\",\"status\": \"CREATED\"},\"SERVER132\": \"1000\"}],\"oauthKey\": \"newtest\",\"SERV ER\": \"1000\"},\"feat ures\": [ 9004, 9005] ,\"d\":\"dd\"}";


        String patternString1 = "\"([^\"]+?[ ]+[^\"]+?)\"\\s*:";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString1);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

        while(matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(1));
           text= text.replaceAll("\""+matcher.group(1)+"\"","\""+(matcher.group(1).replaceAll(" ",""))+"\"");

        }
         System.out.println("Final output:"+text);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I  trim for json values using this code

Answer (score -2):

Remove only the white space on the strings in jason code not all white space on jason code

```java
public String removeWhiwspaceInJasonString(String jsonStr) {
    boolean changeActive = false;
    String output = '';
    for(int i=0; i<jsonStr; i++){

        if(jsonStr.charAt(i) == '"')
            changeActive  =!changeActive;
        else if(changeActive)
          if(jsonStr.charAt(i) == ' ')
             output += '_';
          else
             output += jsonStr.charAt(i);
        else
          output += jsonStr.charAt(i);

    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Manuel string or regular expresion operations are highly discouraged for manpulating JSON strings. Due to specifications there are many data, function formats along with escape char rules.