# Replace dot in all JSON keys in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

For example we have JSON like this but it could be more complicated with many nested blocks:

```
{"TestKey": "TEST", "Test.dots": [{ "child.dot": "child.value.1"}, {"child.dot": "child.value 2"}] }
```

I want replace ALL dots in this JSON string for another character. I found similar solution here: [Replace whitespace in JSON keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228343/replace-whitespace-in-json-keys) but this solution cant handle with ArrayList. Do you have suggestions how to handle with it?

Desired JSON should look like this if we replace dot by underscore:

```
{"TestKey": "TEST", "Test_dots": [{ "child_dot": "child.value.1"}, {"child_dot": "child.value 2"}] }
```

Comment: can u post your code which giving this JSON data? I can help you, all u need is to change your code to give JSON data as you want.

Comment: Thats the problem - JSON is not always the same it cant be mapped to any Object. I need robust solution which just remove the dots.

Answer (score 0):

Delete key node and add again

```
  jObject = new JSONObject(contents.trim());
  Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

  while( keys.hasNext() ) {
         String key = (String)keys.next();
         if ( jObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
               obj.put(key.replaceAll("\\.", ""), 
               obj.get(get(key)));
               obj.remove((key));
        }
```

}

Iterate over json get key replace and remove and put again

Comment: I want replace ALL dots in this JSON keys for another character. Mentioned string is only the example. As I mentioned the final JSON is much more longer. I need general solution for all JSON keys.