# Remove white space from XML element using java

Tags: java, json, xml

I have a JSON as follows

```
String str = {'Emp name' : 'JSON','Emp id' : 1,'Salary' : 20997.00}
```

I want to covert this JSON to XML using java.My java code is here.

```
JSON json= JSONSerializer.toJSON(str);
XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();  

//To Skip the white space from XML data and not from XML Element (By default it does)
    xmlSerializer.setSkipWhitespace(true);  
    //To set type of xml element If it true, it will be type
    xmlSerializer.setTypeHintsCompatibility(true);  
    xmlSerializer.setRootName("book");  
    String xml = xmlSerializer.write( json );  
    System.out.println(xml);
```

I am getting an output if I pass the xml without any space between XML element (i.e Emp name as Empname and Emp id as Empid). I want to remove the whitespace from XML element and not from XML Element content.

Comment: so... what exactly happens when you run this? and what are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: You can remove whitespace from json key rather than xml element. You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30228343/replace-whitespace-in-json-keys

Comment: Get all the JSON keys, iterate through them checking for space(only in keys) and replace it. Will this work?

Answer (score 2):

I decompiled and checked json-lib(2.4) and xom (1.2.5) libraies. Unfortunately there is no such pre/post processors or handlers regarding to key.
This applies both when constructing JSON or building XML as well.

Seems like there is no other way to manually fix keys of JSON. So please check below snippet:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "{'Emp name' : 'JSON','Emp id' : 1,'Salary' : 20997.00, " +
                "'manager' : {'first name':'hasan', 'last name' : 'kahraman'}," +
                "'co workers': [{'first name':'john', 'last name' : 'wick'}, " +
                "{'first name':'albert', 'last name' : 'smith'}]}";

        JsonConfig config = new JsonConfig();
        JSON json = JSONSerializer.toJSON(str, config);

        fixJsonKey(json);

        XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
        //To Skip the white space from XML data and not from XML Element (By default it does)
        xmlSerializer.setSkipWhitespace(true);
        //To set type of xml element If it true, it will be type
        xmlSerializer.setTypeHintsCompatibility(true);
        xmlSerializer.setRootName("book");

        String xml = xmlSerializer.write(json);
        System.out.println(xml);
    }

    private static void fixJsonKey(Object json) {

        if (json instanceof JSONObject) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) json;
            List<String> keyList = new LinkedList<String>(jsonObject.keySet());
            for (String key : keyList) {
                if (!key.matches(".*[\\s\t\n]+.*")) {
                    Object value = jsonObject.get(key);
                    fixJsonKey(value);
                    continue;
                }

                Object value = jsonObject.remove(key);
                String newKey = key.replaceAll("[\\s\t\n]", "");

                fixJsonKey(value);

                jsonObject.accumulate(newKey, value);
            }
        } else if (json instanceof JSONArray) {
            for (Object aJsonArray : (JSONArray) json) {
                fixJsonKey(aJsonArray);
            }
        }
    }
```

Output is as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<book>
    <Empid type="number">1</Empid>
    <Empname type="string">JSON</Empname>
    <Salary type="number">20997.0</Salary>
    <coworkers class="array">
        <e class="object">
            <firstname type="string">john</firstname>
            <lastname type="string">wick</lastname>
        </e>
        <e class="object">
            <firstname type="string">albert</firstname>
            <lastname type="string">smith</lastname>
        </e>
    </coworkers>
    <manager class="object">
        <firstname type="string">hasan</firstname>
        <lastname type="string">kahraman</lastname>
    </manager>
</book>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can switch the JSON framework and/or add another one, have a look at [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome). A simple solution for your problem is a DTO (data transfer object):

```
class Employee {
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("Emp name")
    public String getname() { return name; }

    ...setter...
}
```

See "[Annotations: changing property names](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind#annotations-changing-property-names)"